Dealing with blanks in Power BI
I am trying to calculate **the average time spent from status 1140(start of process) to 2400(end of Purchasing process) ** and then show the split by OR and PO Stages. And after I get the normal average working properly, I need to take out the Weekends.
This is for order approval and placing statuses, therefore for each status progression there needs to be an approval from an employee.
I have a table where one row is one change in the order approval. See sample data:



ID
Or Ty
Original Order No
Order Co
Order Number
Co
Date Updated
User ID
Time
Or Status Stage
Index
Status_ID
OriginalCheck




3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45317
A
0,227303241
PO
37021
2400
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45317
A
0,227303241
PO
37020
2400
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45317
A
0,227303241
PO
37019
2400
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45317
A
0,227303241
PO
37018
2400
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45317
A
0,227303241
PO
37017
2400
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45317
A
0,227303241
PO
37016
2400
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45317
A
0,226180556
PO
32988
2240
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45300
A
0,118263889
PO
32987
2240
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45300
A
0,118252315
PO
29384
2220
1


3136
ON
3136
02147
4731
02147
45320
M
0,556296296
PO
41333
2999
1


3136
O3

02147
3136
02147
45300
A
0,118252315
OR
24121
1999
1


3136
O3

02147
3136
02147
45299
M
0,315983796
OR
3619
1160
1


3136
O3

02147
3136
02147
45299
P
0,315983796
OR
3618
1160
1


3136
O3

02147
3136
02147
45299
Y
0,222592593
OR
3617
1160
1


3136
O3

02147
3136
02147
45299
R
0,369328704
OR
8206
1180
1


3136
O3

02147
3136
02147
45299
Y
0,222581019
OR
822
1140
1


10015
O3
10015
02156
10016
02156
45327
J
0,494652778
PO
26519
2140
1


10015
O3
10015
02156
10016
02156
45327
J
0,494652778
PO
27016
2160
1


10015
O3
10015
02156
10016
02156
45328
J
0,647581019
PO
27017
2160
1


10015
O3
10015
02156
10016
02156
45329
K
0,658078704
PO
28145
2180
1


10015
O3
10015
02156
10016
02156
45329
H
0,695833333
PO
41097
2999
1



Table description:
Or Status Stage:

OR - Order Requsition, PO - Purchase Order;
Stage OR comes Before PO.

Status_ID:

Originaly the Statuses in each Order Stage ranged from 140(Start) till 999(End);
To differenciate the stages I updated the stauses: 1140 - 2999

ID:

Order ID

Date Updated:

The date when the change happened

Time:

At what time the change was made on the [Date Updated] date.

And a Status dimention:



Current Statuss
Or Status Stage
ID




110
OR
1110


130
OR
1130


140
OR
1140


160
OR
1160


180
OR
1180


220
OR
1220


230
OR
1230


240
OR
1240


400
OR
1400


440
OR
1440


999
OR
1999


110
PO
2110


130
PO
2130


140
PO
2140


160
PO
2160


180
PO
2180


220
PO
2220


230
PO
2230


240
PO
2240


400
PO
2400


999
PO
2999



What I did:
I calculated the average time spent from status 1140(start of process) to 2400(end of Purchasing process)(see code below) but the problem is when I try to visualize it in stages.
Average good = 
    
VAR _orders = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT(fctOrderApprovalChain[ID]),
        // fctOrderApprovalChain[Or Status Stage] = "OP",
        fctOrderApprovalChain[Statuss_ID] = 2999,
        REMOVEFILTERS(dimStatus),
        REMOVEFILTERS(fctOrderApprovalChain[Or Status Stage])
    )
    // This gives me a distinct table with the order ID's which have reached the stauss 2999 (further called "_orders")
VAR result = 
    AVERAGEX(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
        _orders,
        "@start", 
        VAR _CurrentOrder = [ID]
        RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            MIN(fctOrderApprovalChain[Date Updated]) + 0,
            fctOrderApprovalChain[ID] = _CurrentOrder
        ) 
        // This Calculates the starting date of the order (further called [@start])
        ,
        // TREATAS(DISTINCT(fctOrderApprovalChain[ID]), 
        "@finish", 
        VAR _CurrentOrder = [ID]
        RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(fctOrderApprovalChain[Date Updated]) +  0,
            fctOrderApprovalChain[ID] = _CurrentOrder
        )
        // This calculates the last date of the order (further called [@finish])
    )
    // This creates a table of the _orders with 2 additional columns - [@start] and [@finish]  
    ,
    [@finish]-[@start]
    // This calculates the difference between the [@start] and [@finish] (weekends included) 
    //NETWORKDAYS([@start],[@finish])
    ) 
    // This returns the average of the [@start] and [@finish] difference. From the _orders 
RETURN
    result

This returns the correct Average Good:

Average of diff is the average of the Table[Diff] column:
Table = 
VAR _orders = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT(fctOrderApprovalChain[ID]),
        // fctOrderApprovalChain[Or Status Stage] = "OP",
        fctOrderApprovalChain[Statuss_ID] = 2400
    )
    
VAR result = 
    // AVERAGEX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        _orders,
        "@start", 
        VAR _CurrentOrder = [ID]
        RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            MIN(fctOrderApprovalChain[Date Updated]),
            fctOrderApprovalChain[ID] = _CurrentOrder
        ),
        //  // TREATAS(DISTINCT(fctOrderApprovalChain[ID]), 
        "@finish", 
        VAR _CurrentOrder = [ID]
        RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(fctOrderApprovalChain[Date Updated]),
            fctOrderApprovalChain[ID] = _CurrentOrder
        ),
        "@OPstart", 
        VAR _CurrentOrder = [ID]
        RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            MIN(fctOrderApprovalChain[Date Updated]),
            fctOrderApprovalChain[ID] = _CurrentOrder,
            fctOrderApprovalChain[Or Status Stage] = "PO"
        ),
        //  // TREATAS(DISTINCT(fctOrderApprovalChain[ID]), 
        "@OPfinish", 
        VAR _CurrentOrder = [ID]
        RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(fctOrderApprovalChain[Date Updated]),
            fctOrderApprovalChain[ID] = _CurrentOrder,
            fctOrderApprovalChain[Or Status Stage] = "PO"
        )
    )
    // ,
    // [@finish]-[@start]
    // )
RETURN
result 

a physical DISCONECTED table of the first code snippet for tests.
But as you can see in the matrix, the averages don't add up.
I think that the problem lies beneath the BLANK values in this matrix:

The weird thing is that for each phase it is correct(I checked it in excel), but the sum should be 6,40(6,39) not 6,24.
Also its weird that for the sample data orders it does add up:

Does anyone know what is going on?
Here is the photo of the model:


